# Offset parameter ignored in getUpdates Telegram bot API

Tags: api, bots, telegram

I am making a telegram bot using the telegram bot web API as described [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

I am using long polling to collect updates for my bot via the method [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates). In order to avoid processing the same message twice I am using the method's offset parameter.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates"
offsetParam = {'offset' : 999}
response = requests.get(url,params=offsetParam)
```

When running this code, one would expect that every update would have an offset greater than 999. However I still get message_id's which are less than 999 as part of the last variable in the code (all of them, as a matter of fact).

Can anyone help me figure out why is the response offset not increasing after this call?

P.S: I'm glad to provide extra info.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked through this using `cURL`.  It's not the `message_id`;  it's the `update_id`.  If `offset` is greater than `update_id`, `cURL` returns only when a new update is available or when `timeout` elapses.  In other words, it long polls.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple. The offset refers to the update_id value.

Other answers claim that message_id is the offset, **this is not the case at the time of writing.**

Answer (score 0):

Offset is message ID, you should obtain that in `result.message_id`, not start from `0`.

Comment: Ok, now I know that the offset actually reffers to  the message_id, thank you. However, the issue still remains. If i still give an offset of 999, I still receive all the previous messages which have a message_id less than 999. I will edit the question to show this

Comment: @DanielHernandez You should set to `message_id+999`, not `999`.